# How to enable field binding in databinding (asp.net visual studio)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, data-binding, dropdown

I'm binding database values (asp.net visual studio)in a dropdown list which is in datagridview
I followed the steps from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YB2pe_C2Tbg

but in data binding step field binding option is disabled(grayed out)
[image]
now how to enable this area?

Comment: it going to be impossible to "guess" what steps you missed in some video.  I have to assume you are attempting to use a edit template inside of a gridview. You can't use a data binding expression for a dropdown list outside of a data bound control like gridview, listview, or say repeater.  So, you have to outline the steps you used and post a re-producible example of what you attempting to do. In fact, we don't even know if you using a gridview or not?

Comment: Hi, the field binding option is disabled usually because the data source is missing in design view. The guess here is that you did not specify the data source in the page. Because usually it's coded in the code-behind file.
If your issue is still not resolved, you can refer to here <https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c334ffd3-a45e-4dd4-87d2-c87c8b0ee2f7/binding-for-selected-value- disabled-grayed-out-greyed-out?forum=aspwebformsdata>, or provide more code information so that more people can help you